# Wordpress: get current user role

Tags: wordpress, function

I have this function to add the current user role as a class in the body.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
        $classes[] = get_user_role();

    return $classes;
}
```

It doesn't work and I know that the problem is `get_user_role()` in this line:

```
 $classes[] = get_user_role();
```

What's wrong in this line?

If I use this line instead, **it works fine**:

```
 $classes[] = "someText";
```

Comment: `get_user_role()` doesn't appear to exist for WP? - Did you assume this was a real WP function or is it your own custom function?

Comment: I thought it was wp function.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the code below:

```
function get_current_user_role() {
   if(is_user_logged_in()) {
       $user = wp_get_current_user();
       $role = (array) $user->roles;
       return $role[0];
   } 
   else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i cant find get_user_role() function in wordpress

I think you are looking for

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

and you can point out the the display name of that user as

```
$current_user->display_name
```

and in body class function

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = $current_user->display_name;

return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use:

```
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
global $current_user;
$classes[] = array_shift($current_user->roles);
}
add_filter('body_class', 'my_body_classes');
```

Works Great!

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use this code

```
  function custom_class($classes) {  
     global $current_user; 
     $user_role = array_shift($current_user->roles);  
     $classes[] = $user_role; 
     return $classes;
    }
  add_filter('body_class','custom_class');
```